# Randomize questions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

my goal is to create a script that will randomly select 5 questions from spreadsheet and insert them into Google Form. I would like to do this with each form opening, so that each respondent has a unique, random set of questions.

Given that there is no option to set a trigger for the respondent to open the form and set random questions with them. I built a script that randomizes the questions every minute. However, there was a problem that when someone starts to fill out the form, and I run the script, the questions will update already in the resolved script!

Do you have any idea how to solve this from within Google Apps Script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656687/7215091

Comment: Related question: [Lock a sheet from updating in between form submissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73876490/1330560)

Comment: The thing is that I would like to run display randomize questions every time a respondent (not editor) opens the form